# Convert these rewrite apache rules to nginx

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, nginx

In my Wordpress, I changed the posts permalinks structure. In order to don't get 404 erros for the old links, I would like to redirect the old permalinks to the new permalinks. [According to this](http://yoast.com/wp-content/permalink-helper.php), the following code must be added in my .htacess so that I can get the redirect working from old posts links to the new posts link:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([^/]+).html$ http://myurl.com/$3
```

That's good, however, I don't use Apache – I use nginx. How can I convert this rules to nginx? I've already tried a apache to nginx online converter, with no success.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you want.  "permanent" is 301 according to [this](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule) page.

```
rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([^/]+).html$" http://myurl.com/$3 permanent;
```

Comment: As per notes given in http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule. `Note: for curly braces( { and } ), as they are used both in regexes and for block control, to avoid conflicts, regexes with curly braces are to be enclosed with double quotes (or single quotes).`  So Rewrite rule will be `rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([^/]+).html$" http://myurl.com/$3 permanent;`